# PHP read CSV & ignore certain columns

Tags: php, csv

I have a simple PHP script that reads a CSV file and generates an array from this:

```
<?php
$file = fopen('food.csv', 'r');
$allfile = [];
$idsColumnsWanted = array(0,1,16);
while (($line = fgetcsv($file)) !== FALSE) {

  $i = 0;

  foreach ($line as $i => $cell) {
      if (!in_array($i, $idsColumnsWanted)) {
          continue;
      }
      $allfile[] = $line;
      $i++;
  }

}
fclose($file);
?>
```

I'd like to display just the data in columns 0, 1 & 16.

I have made an attempt above, but it still outputs the entire CSV.

Comment: While trying to display you can filter out

Comment: well, i think you want to check on key instead of value, `in_array()` checks for the value,  `array_key_exists()` checks for the key

Comment: You do not have to increase the 'i' variable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it with [`array_intersect_key`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-intersect-key.php):

```
$file = fopen('food.csv', 'r');
$allfile = [];

$idsColumnsWanted = array_flip([0, 1, 16]);

while (false !== $fields = fgetcsv($file)) {
    $allfile[] = array_intersect_key($fields, $idsColumnsWanted);
}

fclose($file);
```

Note: if you don't want to preserve the column numbers as keys in your result array, use `array_values(array_intersect_key(...))`.

Comment: When I run this, my array is populated with `null` items. How do I resolve?

Comment: @michaelmcgurk: really? I will make some tests.

Comment: @michaelmcgurk: the "s" was missing in "$id**s**ColumnsWanted"

Comment: Many thanks, @Casimir - that worked perfectly :-) I just need to now figure out how to change the numbers `0`, `1`, `16` to text values :-)

Comment: This is fantastic and works first time @CasimiretHippolyte